# R sum multiple columns with multiple row

Tags: r

So i have this data

```
10 21 22 23 23 43
20 12 26 43 23 65
21 54 64 73 25 75
```

My expected outcome is:

```
142
189
312
```

I tried to use:

```
df = data.matrix(df)
df = colSums(df)
df = as.data.frame(df)
```

However, the sum of values are wrong. I would like to know how to improve or correct this solution?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. Maybe add a `dput(df)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(df)
#[1] 142 189 312
```

Comment: i tried but it says error :x must be numeric, but when i change it to a matrix the values becomes messed up

Comment: @AmosOrg Please check the `str(df)`.  It should be `factor` or `character`.  In that case, convert to `numeric` i.e. `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored as factors. You must convert it to numeric using `as.numeric(as.character())`.

In your situation I suggest to do:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   df[i,]<-as.numeric(as.character(df[i,]))
}
rowSums(df)
```